# Real numbers regenerativity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why are all real numbers not reproducible (I.e some irrational numbers )using integers $x,u\in\mathbb{Z}$ using a function $f(x,u)=x/u$. 
My thought is that when I consider $x=1$,$u$ varies from $1$ to $\infty$.You can get infinite values from $0$ to $1$.Similarly for various values of x,u.
My question is are all real numbers reproducible.
IF not why?

Comment: Have you seen a proof of the fact that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational?

Comment: Oh man, you're not going to like Cantor's diagonal argument!

Comment: If they were there would be integers $x,u$ such that $(x/u)^2=2$, but $x^2=2u^2$ has no solution in integers. The problem is not with covering large numbers but with gaps between fractions for numbers of any size.

Comment: Making $u$ bigger and bigger only allows to approach an arbitary real number as close as we want with rational numbers. This does not mean that we can actually "hit" it. The standard proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, is crystal-clear, no room for serious doubts.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that the Pythagoreer's were also convinced that (at least in the "real world") only rational numbers exist and were clearly disproven by the $\sqrt{2}$-proof. The sad part is that they were not able to accept the fallacy.

Comment: No,i would like to know the reason for that.@peter

Comment: See [Discovery of Irrational Numbers](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/discovery-of-irrational-numbers/).